# O(n) algorithm to find the odd-number-out in array of consecutive integers from 1 to n(not odd numbers)

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm, time-complexity, big-o

I'm having a great deal of trouble trying to figure this question out, and the root of that trouble is creating an algorithm of `O(n)` complexity. Here's the question I'm struggling with:

> An Array `A` of length `n` contains integers from the range `[0, .., n - 1]`. However, it only contains `n - 1` distinct numbers. So one of the numbers is missing and another number is duplicated. Write a Java method that takes `A` as an input argument and returns the missing number; the method should run in `O(n)`.
>
> For example, when `A = [0, 2, 1, 2, 4]`, `oddOneOut()` should return `3`; when `A = [3, 0, 0, 4, 2, 1]`, `oddOneOut()` should return `5`.

Obviously this is an easy problem to solve with an `O(n2)` algorithm, (and most likely `O(n)`, I'm just not seeing it!). I've attempted to solve it using all manner of methods, but to no avail. I'm attempting to solve it in Java, but if you're more comfortable solving it Python, that would be fine as well.

Thank you in advance...

Comment: Are there restrictions on the space you can use as well? I would loop over the array once and get the min and max; then create an array of size range. Then loop over the array a second time placing each element in its slot. You then need to find the missing item in the bucket-sorted array.

Comment: Thank you for the speedy reply! There are not any restrictions on the space used stated in the problem. I'm not familiar with bucker-sort, but from what I just looked up, would this not be o(n logn) ?

Comment: @Turtle-in-a-bash-shell That's because it's not actually bucket sort. It's the equivalent of a set/boolean membership array which takes only O(n) time and O(n) space to create and O(n) time to pass through. But anyways I would recommend looking at the O(1) space solution given by user1952500

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Suppose the number missing is `x` and the duplicate is `y`. If you add all numbers, the sum will be:

```
(n - 1) * n / 2 - x + y
```

From the above, you can find `(x - y)`.....(1)

Similarly, sum the squares of the numbers. The sum will then be:

> `(n - 1) * n * (2 * n - 1) / 6 - x2 + y2`

From the above you get `(x2 - y2)`....(2)

```
(2) / (1) gives (x + y).....(3)
```

(1) + (3) gives `2 * x` and you can thereby find `x` and `y`.

Note that in this solution there is **`O(1)` extra storage** and is **`O(n)` time complexity**. The other solutions above are unnecessarily `O(n)` extra storage.

Code in mixed C/C++ for some more clarity:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int findDup(int *arr, int n, int& dup, int& missing)
{
    int sum = 0;
    int squares = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        sum += arr[i];
        squares += arr[i] * arr[i];
    }

    sum = (n - 1) * n / 2 - sum; // x - y

    squares = (n - 1) * n * (2 * (n - 1) + 1) / 6 - squares; // x^2 - y^2

    if (sum == 0) {
        // no duplicates
        missing = dup = 0;
        return -1;
    }
    missing = (squares / sum + sum) / 2; // ((x^2 - y^2) / (x - y) + (x - y)) / 2 = ((x + y) + (x - y)) / 2 = x

    dup = missing - sum; // x - (x - y) = y

    return 0;
}


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int dup = 0;
    int missing = 0;

    int a[] = {0, 2, 1, 2, 4};

    findDup(a, sizeof(a) / sizeof(int), dup, missing);
    printf("dup = [%d], missing = [%d]\n", dup, missing);

    int b[] = {3, 0, 0, 4, 2, 1};
    findDup(b, sizeof(b) / sizeof(int), dup, missing);
    printf("dup = [%d], missing = [%d]\n", dup, missing);

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
dup = [2], missing = [3]
dup = [0], missing = [5]
```

Some python code:

```
def finddup(lst):
    sum = 0
    sumsq = 0
    missing = 0
    dup = 0
    for item in lst:
        sum = sum + item
        sumsq = sumsq + item * item
    n = len(a)
    sum = (n - 1) * n / 2 - sum
    sumsq = (n - 1) * n * (2 * (n - 1) + 1) / 6 - sumsq
    if sum == 0:
        return [-1, missing, dup]
    missing = ((sumsq / sum) + sum) / 2
    dup = missing - sum
    return [0, missing, dup]

found, missing, dup = finddup([0, 2, 1, 2, 4])
if found != -1:
    print "dup = " + str(dup) + " missing = " + str(missing)

print finddup([3, 0, 0, 4, 2, 1])
```

Outputs:

```
dup = 2 missing = 3
[-1, 0, 0]
```

Comment: Good answer, although it does overflow `long` (and hence needs to use `BigInteger` or a hand-rolled overflow counter) somewhere around `n = 2^22`, which is fewer than fits in memory on a proper computer. Still, any solution runs out of some resource eventually.

Comment: It doesn't really matter whether it overflows if you're careful; the analysis can be adapted to modular arithmetic.

Comment: Hands down best solution. +1

Comment: So how would I implement this as an algorithm? This is what I have for testing in python but I don't see how this would work:                    A = [0, 2, 1, 2, 4]
B = [3, 0, 0, 4, 2, 1]

def oddOneout(list):
 sum = 0
 squares = 0
 for i in list:
  sum = sum + ((i-1)*i/2)
 for i in list:
  squares = squares + ((i - 1) * i * (2 * i - 1) / 6)
  
  
 
  
 print(sum)
 print(squares)
 
 
oddOneout(A)

Comment: Sorry, I don't know how to add code properly formated as a comment.

Comment: You can represent the x, y, (1), (2) and (3) as variables. The sum will be sum = sum + i; Likewise for the squares: squares = squares + i * i; The formulae involving n are the actual sum of numbers and sum of squares formulae.

Comment: I'm still utterly confused; you don't know what x or y are. There is no way to determine what the duplicate is without a sorting algorithm.

Comment: Added code that does not do sorting or anything else as you can see. It is in C++ but should be easily understandable and portable into java / python. The idea is that you are finding x and y. You calculate the sum of the array and there are well known formulae for the sum of the [0..(n-1)] and sum of squares of [0..(n-1)].  Hence you can easily calculate x and y.

Answer (score 16):

Iterate over the array twice: That is still O(n). Create a temporary array of booleans (or a Java BitSet) to hold which numbers you got. Second time you do the loop, check if there is a hole in the array of booleans.

Comment: I'll give this one a go. In researching the problem I thought a Java bitset could be a possible avenue to pursue, but hesitated as I've never employed it; looks like I'm without other options. Thanks for the reply!

Comment: @Turtle-in-a-bash-shell: Once you found a question that solves your problem, you can accept it by clicking the tick next to the answer.

Comment: I guess I'm still confused on how I would use an array of booleans to hold which numbers I have? And why would the second loop show a hole in the array?

Comment: Alternatively, how would I create a BitSet, and why would this work? I guess I don't understand the concept behind it.

Comment: @Turtle-in-a-bash-shell: for our purposes `BitSet` is just a space-optimized vector of `boolean` values. So in the first pass (over the input array), you set index `i` to `true` when you see value `i`. Then in a second pass (over the BitSet) you look for the one index that's still `false`.

Answer (score 4):

Use a hash set and take a single pass to detect which number is the duplicate.  During the same iteration, track the cumulative sum of all the numbers.

Now calculate the expected total if all the numbers were distinct: `n * (n - 1) / 2`.  Subtract the total you found.  You will be left with the "missing" number minus the duplicate.  Add the duplicate back to get your answer.

Since hash table access is constant time and we're using a single pass, this is `O(n)`.  (Note that a single pass isn't strictly necessary: Martijn is correct in noting that a fixed number of passes is still linear complexity.)

Comment: Summing is the elegant way to do this. +1

Comment: That is nicely found, but I'm afraid that using a set is makes it more than O(n). I'm not good at calculating Big-Oh, but I think it is something like O(n^2).

Comment: Look again.  Insert and probe into hash map/set is amortized constant time, assuming you double the container size every time you rehash.  All standard implementations do.

Comment: @MartijnCourteaux no, that's not right. A `HashSet` in Java guarantees [O(1) `add`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashSet.html).

Comment: Note that Martijn's answer in effect uses a hashset fiendishly optimized for this job. He sets the number of hash buckets equal to `n` right at the start in order to avoid rehashing, he uses the trivial hash function, and because we know that the domain of values is 0 ... n-1, hash collisions are impossible so the code to deal with that can be ditched. That is: a hashset reduces to an array if you know enough about the values...

Comment: If I drip down into the Java source code for the add method of a HashSet, I get into the HashMap put method, which has a for loop. How do you ever want to store things without duplicating them in O(1)? Is there an article that I can read about this subject?

Comment: @MartijnCourteaux This may be helpful: http://www.cs.cornell.edu/courses/cs312/2008sp/lectures/lec20.html

Comment: @phs: Thanks! I will read this tomorrow. Now, I'm going to take some sleep.

Answer (score 1):

This might be of interest, although I'm not certain under what conditions (if any) it performs best. The idea is that we're going to move each element into its correct place in the array (`0` to index 0, etc), until it becomes clear what is missing and what is extra.

```
def findmissing(data):
    upto = 0
    gap = -1
    while upto < len(data):
        #print data, gap
        if data[upto] == upto:
            upto += 1
            continue
        idx = data[upto]
        if idx is None:
            upto += 1
            continue
        data[upto], data[idx] = data[idx], data[upto]
        if data[upto] == data[idx]:
            print 'found dupe, it is', data[upto]
            data[upto] = None
            gap = upto
            upto += 1
        elif data[upto] is None:
            gap = upto
    return gap

if __name__ == '__main__':
    data = range(1000)
    import random
    missing = random.choice(data)
    print missing
    data[missing] = data[0]
    data[0] = random.choice(data[1:])
    random.shuffle(data)
    print 'gap is', findmissing(data)
```

It's O(n) because every step *either* increments `upto` *or* moves a value into its "correct" place in the array, and each of those things can only happen `n` times.

Comment: Great idea. If you needed to keep a copy of the data, it's O(n) extra storage, but if not, it should be the simplest to implement. And twice as fast on average?

Comment: @clwhisk: it's *probably* slower than user1952500's answer (because that does a single sequential pass over the data) and quite possibly Martijn's (which does non-sequential access to the bitset on the first pass, but mine does non-sequential access to the much larger input array, so will probably provoke more cache misses). I just think it's interesting.